# Is Umbraco DateFolders working on 6.2 or 7.x?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco6, umbraco7

Does anyone know if DateFolders (and AlphabetFolders for that matter) is working on Umbraco 6.2 or 7.x?

Answer (score 1):

[AutoFolders](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/autofolders) should work in v6 (and supports alphabet folders too). I'm one of the devs that is currently maintaining the project and we have it running on various v6 instances (I haven't tested it on 6.2 yet, but nothing has changed that should break it).

Autofolders WON'T work on v7, but for v7 you could use a Container Document Type, which does away with some of the need for Date Folders.

Comment: For Umbraco 7 is that the "Enable list view" option? I suppose a follow-up question would be, "Is there a backwards compatible option for Umbraco 6 to have list view nodes like in Umbraco 7?"

Comment: Yes, that's the enable list view option! I'm not aware of a list view option that works in v6, the problem is that to do that, you'd have to rewrite all of the content trees.......